# How to get parent value and last replaced value in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata, hierarchy

I have a scenario for which I need help with. I am kind of new to stack overflow so let me know if I make any mistakes in asking my question. Welcome your feedback.

I am working with a table in SQL Server where the values are as follows:

```
    OldValue    NewValue    Date
------------------------------------
    1             2       2016-08-01
    2             3       2016-08-03
    101           102     2016-08-06
    102           103     2016-08-08
    103           105     2016-08-14
    201           202     2016-08-06
    202           203     2016-08-08
    203           205     2016-08-14
    205           209     2016-08-18
```

I am trying to put forward a query that will get the oldest and the newest value by which the old one is replaced with. I am looking for an output that looks like this.

```
   OldValue     NewValue  
--------------------------
     1             3              
    101           105    
    201           209
```

The query I put forward for this is as follows:

```
select 
    a.OldCPN, b.NewCPN 
from 
    test..TestTable a 
inner join 
    TestTable b on a.NewCPN = b.OldCPN and a.date <= b.date
```

With the above query, I am getting all the values that are replaced at the intermediate levels also. But I would need only a row that has the oldest values and the newest one by which it is replaced with.

Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming the Value are in ascending order; newer date as larger value

using a recursive CTE

```
; with
cte as
(
    -- parent record
    select  parent = OldValue, OldValue, NewValue, Date
    from    sample_data d
    where   not exists
        (
            select  *
            from    sample_data x
            where   x.NewValue  = d.OldValue
        )

    union all

    -- child
    select  parent = c.parent, d.OldValue, d.NewValue, d.Date
    from    cte c
        inner join sample_data d    on  c.NewValue = d.OldValue
)
select  parent as OldValue, max(NewValue) as NewValue
from    cte 
group by parent
```

EDIT : change the last part of the query to below to handle non-ascending value

```
select  *
from
(
    select  parent as OldValue, NewValue, Date, rn = row_number() over (partition by parent order by Date desc)
    from    cte 
) c
where   c.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. I am not much proficient with hierarchical queries in SQL Server. This query has expanded my horizons of thinking.

Comment: Just wanted to check, is there something that can be done if the values are not in increasing order.?